# Which is the most accurate method to calculate the solenoid coil inductance?

Tags: ac, power-electronics, coil

I generally use the Wheeler formula to calculate it. However, the accuracy is getting lower when I calculate bigger size coils. I am looking for a method that includes the pitch of the turns, and a more accurate calculation method for the bigger size coils.

Comment: Please embed the "Wheeler formula" and explain what you mean by "air-gapped". Please also demonstrate that the accuracy is getting lower - explain how you conclude this.

Comment: Wheeler limitations are well documented https://www.fastfieldsolvers.com/

Comment: I've recently found this website with huge manual on inductance calculation http://g3ynh.info/zdocs/magnetics/part_1.html

Comment: Thank you AlexVB.